# Single Query to get paginated data and all possible filters from the obtained results

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, e-commerce, eloquent-relationship

I am writing a query to perform search for eCommerce. I need to meet 3 search criteria.

1. Search by category id
2. Search by keyword
3. Search by product type (featured, hot, new)

Also i need to extract all possible filters to show user from the filtered results(not paginated results).

I have the following relationships.

```
products
products -> images,
products -> translation,
products -> categories,
products -> variants,
products -> brand
products -> category
products -> addons
products -> product_attributes
```

What i am doing is first get all products based on search criteria. Extract all possible filters from the obtained results. Then paginate the results using `LengthAwarePaginator`.

This approach works fine for small set of products. But now i am having more than 4k products. When my query is executed the memory is exhausted due to so many relations. I have reduced number of columns in product and all relations. Also processing time increases up to 6 secs which i can not afford.

These are the filters i need to extract from the obtained set

```
attributes
brands
categories
min_price
max_price
```

The idea is that when user searches a category filters are displayed in side bar which fall under that category. When user selects some filters and apply search the new filtered results are obtained with pagination. Still i extract possible filters from new results.

I need suggestion as what to do in this situation. Please help.

Comment: sorry for to ask this, but why you need to use LengthAwarePaginator ? isnt you could just use 

Products::paginate(15), if you are using the Laravel Eloquent

Comment: if i directly paginate the results how am i going to get filters from search criteria

Comment: you could use the if statement for the where section before you call the paginate, and also you just need to use leftJoin or join in laravel eloquent to get the filter table

and sorry for ask this, because i really dont get how you write your code

Comment: @Kelvin what should be in my if condition?

Comment: check the request is empty or not like if(request()->has('max_price') ){$query->where() }

Comment: so like @M Khalid Junaid said, Later on you can break your possible filters single query (which may have joins from relation table) in to multiple queries it may increase DB calls but will provide benefit in terms of performance.

Comment: the above condition in already incorporated.

Comment: ah my bad, sorry i didnt notice the "Extract all possible filters from the obtained results"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to have a separate paginated query for your products and a separate query to get possible filters based on user selection, get this information directly from DB and not to cook/filter data from laravel helper methods or in code. On DB side there are several methods to optimize query performance if relations are formed correctly and properly indexed. If you perform this extraction from code it will surely increases memory usage of server.

Later on you can break your possible filters single query (which may have joins from relation table) in to multiple queries it may increase DB calls but will provide benefit in terms of performance.